3d polygon area calculation algorithm
Hi I need some help with this question.
We have a list of Points of (x, y, z) and these points make a polygon and I want to implement a pseudocode that can calculate this polygon area in 3D space.
what I tried has a problem that when I give something with this order: (0,0,0), (2,2,0), (2,0,0), (0,2,0) I get 0.0 for my area answer.
what should I do ?
    public double calculateArea(Polygon polygon) {
        List<Point> points = polygon.getPoints();
        int n = points.size();
        double area = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Point p1 = points.get(i);
            Point p2 = points.get((i + 1) % n);
            area += p1.getX() * p2.getY() - p1.getY() * p2.getX();
        }

        return Math.abs(area) / 2.0;
    }


It seems to me that 0 is the correct answer in this case.  Your shape is not actually a polygon - it's two triangles that are equal in area and that touch at one vertex.  You're traversing one triangle anticlockwise and the other clockwise, so their areas cancel out.  Of course, you'll need to beef up your algorithm once you start having z values other than 0.

No matter how you slice it,  polygons by their nature are 2D (aka a plane figure). All polygons are in 3D space with with z usually set to 0.

You need to find the normal vector of the polygon, then you need to find the difference between that normal vector and the vertical vector, and then you need to rotate the polygon by the negative of that difference so as to make it flat.
Once you do that, all of the Z coordinates in your "3D polygon" should become equal, or roughly equal.  Then, you can get rid of the Zs, and proceed with a normal area-of-2D-polygon calculation.

Actually, the standard algorithm for finding the area of an irregular polygon certainly DOES involve division by 2.  I believe OP got that part of the calculation correct.  Obviously, he hasn't done anything about rotating the polygon into the XY plane, but his sample polygon is already in that plane.

@DawoodibnKareem wh00ps, okay, I will remove that part.  Thanks.
